# GitHub Question - Why close as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[Sync Branch and staying up to date with a project using GitHub for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845740/how-to-stay-up-to-day-with-a-project-on-github-using-github-gui)

I'm curious as to why this would be closed as off-topic with a suggestion to use SuperUser.  It falls within two of the four categories for SO topics:

> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development

GitHub (and other source control) sync issues are generally not encountered outside of software development.  (I know there are counterexamples, but I'd venture even most of those are coders using VC for non-code),

Comment: The question definitely doesn't belong on SU, but I'm afraid it is too broad for SO either.

Comment: I'm actually alright with this question.  There's a viable solution for it, either through Github's UI or through Git.

Comment: Maybe tools should be split out to a separate site? SO is very 'code' focused these days (even if the site description includes other things).

Comment: @steve ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Tools are On-Topic for [main].** `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake did you read my comment? I'm making a suggestion that we move them into a separate site.

Comment: @steve which means moving them to some site **that is not [main]**, correct?!?! I read your comment `:P :P :P` **Did you read *mine*?** `:P :P :P`

Comment: @Cupcake. Correct. I've also previously tried posting non-code questions that fit into the current 'on-topic' list, and been downvoted because 'show me the code'. Why not change SO to make it purely code-related stuff (which 99% of it is anyway), and move the other topics to other sites (e.g. programming).

Comment: @steve which of your questions got downvoted because they didn't have code? Did they get a net-negative score?

Comment: @Cupcake IIRC I gave up and deleted it..

Comment: good news is that you've been un-closed since posting this...

Comment: 'Asking for tools' is different than 'asking about tools'. 'Asking for' is prohibited because it might attract spammers who recommend their own tool. This question is legit and should not have been closed.

Comment: Can't one just move the question to SU (or other site) transparently? I've tried to use automatic keywords suggestion tools based on bayesian algorithms and I think this (the best suited site) could be even suggested automatically and then voted ... With SO Network growing rapidly, I think this is the only good solution in longer perspective!

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier it wasn't my question, I just had the same question and was searching for it.  With tongue moderately in cheek, I think we could support a SE site just for git :)

Answer (score -7):

It should be closed as "too broad" or "primarily opinion based" given how many barrel-on questions are being asked.

> Do I: Fork the repo, or Clone in desktop? [...] Does forking a repo mean you will automatically incorporate the future changes made by others on Github or are those changes ignored? What about cloning? [...] With whom am I sharing my local commits? Is it the origin source? And, whose changes am I "pulling down"? [...] Lastly, what is the best technique (using the Github GUI) if I want to: [...]

Ultimately though, it's a question of "how do I subscribe to updates?"

In that instance it's now about how to use a web app's UI instead of anything programming with its API and would fall toward [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Related: [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6312/27077). The answer there also says that GitHub questions should go to [webapps.se].